# No free space on system & locked out of recovery mode because firmware password, Linux to rescue?

Tags: boot, osx, darwin

This is a bit of a tragedy of circumstances.

I was deleting all free space on my latest install of OS X with

```
diskutil secureErase freespace 4 "/Volumes/Macintosh HD"
```

and unfortunately it failed. The way that it fails, it leaves behind massive temp files that basically bring down my free space to around `8MB`, with "System" eating up around 250GB at this point, its junk created by diskutil.

When I was able to login still, I couldn't find the files created and even had the odd situation where even after reboot, after deleting say a 1GB .iso, I would have it once again drop down to 8MB.

I tried going into recovery mode or shell at startup with CMD+{R, S}, but I forgot my firmware password and so can't get into those modes.

Situation become so bad that trying to log in hangs, because there is no space on disk and presumably login process uses up temp file space. a 500GB hard drive reduced to ~8MB free space.

Besides the Apple option of redoing the firmware, which takes a week and results in fresh install anyway, is there a Linux way to solve this? That is, somehow have machine boot into Linux and from there solve the issue of firmware or at finding the large files and deleting them. This is a Mid-2015 MacBook, 15' inch FWIW, as I saw some solutions to getting around the firmware password by removing memory, but that was for older models and doesn't seem to apply to this one.

TL;DR: Is there a way to boot into Linux even if firmware encrypted on MacBook, or load it somehow from just login screen since trying to login never succeeds because system out of disk space. (I did hear of some people being able to boot into Linux because EFI was same?)

Comment: Unfortunately a legitimate question again closed by this SO, this community just continues to disappoint.